# Does calling sigemptyset() after sigsetjmp() with non-zero argument invalidate its effect?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

Given the following piece of C code:

```c
sigsetjmp(env, 1);
sigemptyset(&env->__saved_mask);
```

My question is if the second line invalidates the meaning of using the second argument of `sigsetjmp` to a non-zero value, as per my understanding, this following code should have the same meaning:

```c
sigsetjmp(env, 0);
```

Can anyone confirm?

I have tried using debugging tool to affirm my hypothesis but I want to be extra certain that they have the same meaning. the debugging tools seems to show that in both cases `env->__saved_mask` would have all values set to 0.

Comment: "I have tried using debugging tool to affirm my hypothesis" This particular spaghetti-programming family of  functions comes with so many cases of severe, dangerous undefined behavior associated with it that you will never be able to verify that the functions "work" through trial & error. You have to study what guarantees the ISO C and POSIX (don't) give in theory, then code accordingly. Or alternatively follow best practices and avoid setjmp.h like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding how what you're doing is nonportable (`sigjmp_buf` doesn't have standardized internals), then no. Clearing the saved signal mask won't make it as if you hadn't saved the signal mask.

You'd need to clear the field that says whether the mask was saved in the first place. Clearing the saved mask would just make `siglongjmp` restore the effective mask to an empty mask even if it wasn't empty at the `sigsetjmp` call.